# Classe de conexão mysqli no php e SELECT

Tags: php, mysqli

O código de conexão com o banco de dados que montei está funcionando, mas quando faço uso de um SELECT aparece um erro e não consegui resolver.

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'projetoxyz');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

class conexao extends mysqli {

    public $servidor;
    public $usuario;
    public $senha;
    public $banco;

    function __construct($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco) {
        $this->servidor = $servidor;
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->senha = $senha;
        $this->banco = $banco;
    }

    public function conectar()
    {
        try
        {
            parent::__construct($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->banco);
            if(mysqli_connect_errno() != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception('Erro ao conectar!');
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

$mysqli = new conexao(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

#################################################################

if( !function_exists('nomecidade') ) {

    function nomecidade($cidade=NULL) {

        if(!isset($mysqli)) {
          $mysqli = new conexao(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        }

        $mysqli->conectar();

        $cidade = trim($cidade);

        $cidade = $mysqli->real_escape_string($cidade);

        /* Em WHERE, o campo Código é INTEGER, o SELECT pega o código da Cidade e retorna o nome da cidade relacionada ao código*/

        $sqlCidade = "SELECT 
                            `Nome` 
                        FROM 
                            `municipio` 
                        WHERE 
                            `Codigo` = ? 
                        LIMIT 
                            1
                        ;";

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlCidade);

        $stmt->bind_param("i", $cidade);

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('Cidade indefinida');

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $cidade = stripslashes( $row['Nome'] );

        $stmt->close();

        return $cidade;

    }
}

echo nomecidade('1100056');
?>
```

O erro que apresenta na tela é o seguinte:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in F:\xampp\htdocs\projetoxyz\conn\conn.php:67

Stack trace: #0
F:\xampp\htdocs\projetoxyz\index.php(331): nomecidade('1100056') #1 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\projetoxyz\index.php on line 67

Comment: Amigo, esse código foi copiado? Você está usando aspas simples de duas maneiras, isso pode causar problemas. Você já conseguiu realizar outra consulta antes? O ideal é seguir os padrões da w3: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: A conexão sim, foi copiada.

Comment: Fiz como sugerido, mas como uso o escape_string dentro da minha query SELECT ?

Comment: Seu SELECT nem precisa de aspas:  $sql = "SELECT Nome FROM municipio WHERE Codigo = ? LIMIT 1";

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você não criou o `statment`, para só então usar o `prepare`. Pois ao chamar a função prepare será retornado um `boolean` (que resulta no erro que você recebeu, pois um valor booleano não vai ter a propriedade `bind_param`). Faça Algo como:

```
//......
$stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sqlCidade);

$stmt->bind_param("i", $cidade);

$stmt->execute();
//.......
```